# javascript replace with regex wilcard

Tags: javascript, regex

I am really struggling learning regular expressions. I am trying to find all span tags and remove any ids or classes or any other info and remove them from the string....and failing miserably.

```
var str = '<span class="red" id="num1">foo</span>words<span class="blue">bar</span>';
//What I want to end up with '<span>foo</span>words<span>bar</span>';
str = str.replace(/<span+([*])+\>/g, '');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant information back in...

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is lots of fun. Been playing around with it myself lately.
You want to select the start of a span tag and grab all that exists until the end of the tag. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xL20qqka/1/)

```
var str = '<span class="red" id="num1">foo</span>words<span class="blue">bar</span>';
str = str.replace(/<span.+?\>/g, '<span>');
console.log(str);
```

Explaination: the .+? grabs any char (.) as many times as it takes (+?) until it reaches the end of the tag (>). Without the question mark the + will take all things, not stopping (greedy). Don't forget, since you are replacing, to put the '' tag back!

Comment: Haha no worries, and some useful links to help: [Regex Tester](https://regex101.com/) this you can use to test your regex's to see if they are matching what you want. [Regex Info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) This one has all you could want and more of regex's. I spent a lot of time lately here and learned much.